# Add all Visual Studio unit tests with a specific TestCategory to a new Resharper testsession

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, resharper-9.0

In Visual Studio, in the Test Explorer window, when I group the tests on 'traits', the tests are grouped on a specific category (the `public sealed class TestCategoryAttribute` class I've put on the unit test)

Is there a way to do the same thing in the Resharper 'unit test sessions' window?

I would like to create a new session with all the tests which have a specific category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but is a multi-step process:

1. Create a session that includes all of your tests (or at least all tests in the target category)
2. In that session, go to Options -> Group by -> Categories
3. Right-click the category in the results pane and select "Create New Session"

Answer (score 0):

You could add the annotation Category() to the test method.

```
[Test]
[Category("MyCategory")]
public void MyTestMethod_Example()
{
    // ...
}
```